# How do i iterate json object

Tags: json

this json formate have basically two array object so i am lit bit confused that how do i iterate these two object and display separately.

```js
[
   {
      "todays_birthday":[
         {
            "member_id":"1",
            "member_name":"Subhash Chander Chandna",
            "member_number":"490",
            "member_dob":"1995-06-30"
         },
         {
            "member_id":"4",
            "member_name":"Mrs. Bimla Rani",
            "member_number":"500",
            "member_dob":"1946-06-30"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "tommorow_birthday":[
         {
            "member_id":"3",
            "member_name":"Jagdish Kumar Pahuja",
            "member_number":"490",
            "member_dob":"1946-07-01"
         },
         {
            "member_id":"5",
            "member_name":"Raja Ram",
            "member_number":"500",
            "member_dob":"1946-07-01"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: What language are you trying to parse this in?

Comment: What language are you using? Json is just a schema. You need a programming language to parse it.

Comment: solved .. i need only todays dob so

var data = dictinary2[0].token1;

  for(var i in data)
  {
    var member_id = data[i].member_id;
    var member_name = data[i].member_name;
    console.log(member_id + ' ' + member_name);
  }

Comment: not any language ... only using javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your json could be formed as an object with two properties (`today_birthdays` and `tomorrow_birthdays`) and inside each property you get the array of birthdays.

Like that:

```
{
  today_birthdays: [
    //birthdays
  ],
  tomorrow_birthdays: [
    //birthdays
  ]
}
```

And so you could iterate through the birthdays, for example, with `lodash` (in JavaScript):

```
_(obj.today_birthdays).forEach(function(birthday) {
    //use birthday var..
}
```